# Реализация функции в postgresql (умножение )

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql

Как реализовать функцию, которая находит средний чек по разным группам товаров в postgresql? Обязательно через одну функцию, а не выборку.
Есть вот такая таблица:

```
create table stocks (id int, product char(25), orders int, age int, cost int);
```

Уже заполненная из 100 строк.

1. Нужно, чтобы функция умножала `orders` на `cost` и выводила результат как таблицу (Нахождение среднего чека)
2. Чтобы мы вводили имя продукта в консоли, например, телефон или книга, и происходила сортировка. Вывод будет как 1 строчка: книга, количество заказов, стоимость.
3. Нужно объединить пункт 1 и 2. Результат функции должен быть в 1 строчке такой: (вводим название продукта, например книга) и получаем: книга, средний чек.

Comment: Нашёл встроенную функцию, но можно как реализовать её в моём случае: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31965998/cumulative-multiply-in-postgres

Answer (score 0):

Функция:

```
CREATE FUNCTION avg_receipt(p_name char(25)) 
RETURNS TABLE (product char(25), orders int, cost int, avg_r int)
AS $$ BEGIN 
RETURN QUERY SELECT stocks.product, stocks.orders, stocks.cost, (stocks.orders * stocks.cost) avg_rec FROM stocks WHERE stocks.product = p_name; 
RETURN; 
END; $$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

Пример вызова функции:

```
SELECT avg_receipt('Martin Eden');
```